# Running batch files through java program: The CATALINA_HOME environment variable is not defined correctly

Tags: java, batch-file, tomcat, environment-variables, processbuilder

I have code that runs batch files in windows perfectly fine. (hey.bat just prints something simple)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    static String dir1 = "C:\\Users\\Name\\Desktop\\hey.bat";
    ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(dir1);

    try {
        Process process = processBuilder.start();

        StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));

        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            output.append(line + "\n");       
        }
        int exitVal = process.waitFor();
        if (exitVal == 0) {
            System.out.println(output);       
            System.exit(0);
        } else {
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

However, when I call a different batch file named shutdown.bat, one that is supposed to shutdown Tomcat, it gives the error

> The CATALINA_HOME environment variable is not defined correctly. This
>   environment variable is needed to run this program

When I double click shutdown.bat it works perfectly fine, so why would it give an error when being run through java? Shouldn't all the dependencies be bundled into that batch file? Thanks

Comment: Are you sure shutdown.bat runs fine when you double click it or does a command window appear for a short time and then disappear?

Comment: @clav when I double click, the dialog opens for 1-2 seconds and says 
Using CATALINA_BASE: "somedir"
Using CATALINA_HOME: "somedir"
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: "somedir"
Using JRE_HOME: "somedir"
Using CLASSPATH: "somedir" then closes again